# equational proccess for obtaining the period of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm reading a book where you are asked to find the period of $f(x) = \sin 8X$

The process is this:

$g(x + T) = g(x)$
$\sin 8(x+T) = \sin 8x \implies 8(x+T) = 8x+2\pi$ // this is the step I don't understand
$8x + 8T = 8x + 2\pi$
$8T = 2\pi$
$T = \frac{\pi}{4}$

My question is: why did the author added $2\pi$ to the second member when he cancelled both sinus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the periodicity of $\sin$, $\sin (x  + 2\pi) = \sin x$. To find the period of your function, you use this periodicity of $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

To find the *minimum* period $T$, set: $$\sin(8(x+T)) = \sin(8x) \quad \iff \quad \sin(8x+ 8T) = \sin(8x)$$

Let $u = 8x$, then the second equality becomes $$\sin(u + 8T) = \sin(u)$$

so $8T$ must be the minimum period of $\sin(u)$ which is known to be $2 \pi$.